# How to free up port 3268 windows

Tags: windows, ldap, port

I have a docker container that has a LDAP server and listens on 3268 port number. But i see that the port is already used on my machine so the docker if failing to load up.
How should i free up port 3268 on my machine.
I have tried netsh -a -b command, but the port does not show up there.

Comment: Have you tried Tcpview from sysinternals to find the application that opened the port?

Comment: I'll second using something like tcpview to see what has actually opened the port, but the Windows "well known" service on port 3268 is the global catalog service. If your Docker host machine is a domain controller, it's going to be the directory service opening the port. And, FWIW, 3269 is the secure GC port. If it's the DC using the port, your best bet would be to map another port to the container's 3268. Convincing AD to use different ports is ... not ideal.